# Xero to DataFactory Setup

Tags: etl

How can I setup my data factory to link to xero.

I am looking for a 'how to on this'

MSDN documentation doesn't provide enough information, I need a step by step guide

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. First guide I would recommend reading is https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then please [edit] your question and exactly state what problem you're facing and what you've tried to solve but didn't work.

Comment: It seems like this data factory component is not really functional yet. In the feedback section of the documentation many users reported that this components does not seem to work.

Comment: I also found that the component does not work. Microsoft confirmed they are having issues with the connector

Comment: Anyone found a workaround with the connector ? Mine still does not work